# Exchange Web Services (EWS) requests are delayed if connection is idle too long

Tags: exchangewebservices

When using EWS my requests experience severe delays if I wait more than 25 seconds between requests.

The initial request is always severely delayed, but subsequent requests are handled quickly as long as I don't wait more than 25 seconds between requests. (I'm calling AutodiscoverUrl before the initial request).

I can make different requests against different folders, and as long as I'm within the 25 seconds, they are handled quickly.

If I wait longer than 25 seconds, I experience the delay again; subsequent requests remain fast if I don't wait more than 25 seconds.

What is causing this delay when I wait too long between requests?

Is it possible to configure EWS or the server so that this delay is not experienced? What determines this 25 second period?

Update:

1. I've reproduced this behavior using EWS Editor against three different Exchange Servers. Two hosted externally, and one hosted internally.
2. This is only a problem within one of our internal domains. So this is ***not*** an EWS issue per se.

Comment: You need to share some of the code your using, I would also suggest you try using the ewseditor https://ewseditor.codeplex.com/ as and do some testing (eg can you reproduce the issue with this). Consider enabling tracing and look at the underlying calls and routing. Mostly likely its an infrastructure issue eg load balancer but you need to show the code a fault